# In BaseX, what is the difference between a database and a collection?

Tags: xquery, basex

The BaseX documentation uses the word "collection" in a way that makes its meaning unclear. Is a collection simply another word for a database, or is it a distinct construct? If the latter, what commands are used to manipulate collections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### About Collections and Databases

The [XQuery documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#dt-available-docs) does not speak about databases, but collections - thus there is the name collection to conform to the specs. Yet the specification does not define what a collection is, this is implementation dependent. While other systems [like Marklogic allow multiple collections in a database](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/collections), BaseX regards one collection as a single database.

From the [BaseX Documentation Wiki](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Databases):

> In BaseX, **a database is a pretty light-weight concept and can be compared to a collection.**
>   It contains an arbitrary number of resources, addressed by their unique database path.

It is easy and a cheap operation to join over documents from multiple collections/databases, so split up as seams reasonable to you. Actually using multiple databases instead of one can have a positive effect on concurrency.

### Managing Databases in BaseX

Databases are managed using [BaseX Commands](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands).

Most of interest will be

- [`CREATE DB [name] ([input])`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#CREATE_DB): Create a new database with a given name and input document or XML fragment
- [`OPEN [name]`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#OPEN): Open a database as default collection
- [`DROP DB [name]`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#DROP_DB): Deletes a database

#### Managing Databases Using XQuery

For some operations there are also BaseX-specific [XQuery-functions in the Database Module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module), but using them is somewhat restricted by XQuery Update's [Pending Update List](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#Pending_Update_List).

*Disclaimer: I'm somewhat involved within the BaseX team.*